# I'm new here! DV, OP, VTC, VTD, huh? Help me learn the jargon / lingo!

Tags: discussion, faq, new-users

We do have quite a bit of lingo / jargon on the Stack Exchange (SE) network. Some of it is common to Internet platforms in general, some of it is specific to SE, and some of it is unique to this site and the related fields on topic here.

Here's the goal(s):

1. Help new users learn our lingo / jargon!
2. Post the term or concept as community wiki (CW) so that others may edit/add to it.
3. Define any and all jargon used in your post, even if other posts do this already (assume your reader knows nothing).
4. If a category already exists (such as acronyms), add to the existing answer (don't post a new one).

Answer (score 8):

### Acronyms

- **Q&A** — question and answer. The main purpose of this site.
- **UV** — upvote. This refers to voting positively (up) on someone else's post (i.e. you found that post to be useful).
- **DV** — downvote. This refers to voting negatively (down) on someone else's post (i.e. you did *not* find that post to be useful).
- **OP** — original poster. This refers to the author of the question that a post is attempting to answer, or that a comment is referencing.
- **VTC** — vote to close (also 'VtC'). This refers to voting to put a question 'on hold' because [it does not meet the question criteria](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/867/423). **CV** (short for 'close vote') can refer to individual votes cast to accomplish this.
- **VTD** — vote to delete (also 'VtD'). This refers to voting to delete a post.
- **SE** — Stack Exchange. The network of sites that this Q&A is a part of.
- **Meta** — [Meta is the part of the site](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) where users discuss the workings and policies of Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange rather than discussing the analysis of the Biblical text itself. It is separated from the main Q&A to reduce noise there while providing a legitimate space for people to ask how and why this site works the way it does.
- **BH** — Biblical Hermeneutics. This is the name of this site. You will also see people use 'BH.SE' to refer to the site, i.e. Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange.
- **C.SE** — [Christianity Stack Exchange](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/). Another Q&A site on the Stack Exchange network that is dedicated to questions and answers about Christianity.
- **MY.SE** — [Mi Yodeya Stack Exchange](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/) (also 'J.SE' or 'Judaism.SE').  Another Q&A site on the Stack Exchange network that is dedicated to questions and answers about Judaism.