# Introductory Section

Tags: feature-request

I am awe-struck by the level of knowledge "exhibited" in this site! The Help Topics merely explain how to use the site and what it is. Those troubling questions that require simple, howbeit insightful answers are not helped by researching the questions and answers. Can there be "help" topics that will direct near-ignorant newcomers on how to beef up themselves before delving into this kind of knowledge (like preliminary year class of a university)?

Comment: Some past questions you may find helpful: [What good reference works on Biblical studies are available (freely) online?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/639/423)

Comment: [I'm new here! DV, OP, VTC, VTD, huh? Help me learn the jargon / lingo!](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/916/423)

Comment: Not from this site, but a great collection of resources: [How to Get an Advanced Bible Degree for Free](https://www.logos.com/grow/how-to-get-an-advanced-bible-degree-for-free/), much of which links to YouTube videos of courses and [BiblicalTraining courses](https://www.biblicaltraining.org/)