# What makes a good/bad question?

Tags: discussion

Hi I have only just joined BH but have already recognised that this is going to be a great place to learn and develop my skills of biblical interpretation. I also recognise that this is going to happen most effectively by asking more questions than I answer so I hope that in the vein of James 1:19 I will be quick to listen but slow to speak!

With that in mind I would like to ask the following question: what makes a good question on BH-SE? How should I frame it? What information should I include? On the flip side of this, what makes a bad question? How can I make it as easy as possible for the contributor to answer it?

This might seem ridiculously simple or stupid but I am new to SE and want to make the most of this resource.

Please excuse me if I have posted this in the wrong section.

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I put together [a flowchart for asking on questions on BH.SE](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/867/423) awhile back that you may find helpful. It links to numerous meta posts and quotes from relevant portions of them. If that post answers your question(s), let me know. If not, feel free to ask for more specifics.

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Flow chart is especially helpful. I will take the time properly digest the rest of the information before asking further questions. Examples of good and bad questions are also helpful as well as the sections that address the motivation behind the question. Ie. discussion vs. Listening/learning.

Comment: @LiamM I'm glad you found it helpful :)