# What defines a proper question?

Tags: discussion, answers, questions, clarity, validity

I was looking through the questions and found [this one](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/78879/what-are-the-implications-of-1-peter-320-in-terms-of-the-scope-of-the-flood-jud).  I found the comments to be somewhat odd. So I thought here would be the place to ask a clarifying question.

**On the one hand,** I probably wouldn't venture to answer this question due to the sprawling nature of the question.  It is framed as if it's a simple question with a simple answer.  But there are complications with the question due to the part of the bible being referenced. Here are some of these complications:

- This part of the bible is less clear than other parts of the bible. What Peter is actually *saying* (not in terms of Textual criticism), but in terms of hermeneutics is a live issue.
- This part of the bible touches on many theological issues. And as a result, it would take an exhaustive answer to faithfully address the issues at hand
- An answer to this question would have to encompass more than just one isolated verse. And very few of our readers would have the patience to read through a faithful treatment of the verses. And, in my experience, if one does try to give an extensive justification in the question, then the question gets closed down for "turning the question into a Master's Thesis."

**On the other hand,** I was caught off guard by this comment:

> The question contains a number of difficulties - it assumes
> "predestination" and that the "spirits in prison" are people rather
> than demons. This makes it difficult to answer because of these
> unjustified assumptions. You must justify these before an answer can
> be made. Who said that all had to be killed by the flood? –  Dottard

Are there now topics that are off-limits for discussion? Are these topics a pariah now:

- Presdestination?
- Who was in prison (in 1 Peter 3)?

Considering the fact that, up until recent generations, the church was united in concluding that the words 'spirits in prison' were not exclusively referring to demons, it seems odd that the burden of proof wouldn't be on those who discount the prevailing view to offer up their own proof (that 'spirits in prison' can only refer to demons).

Furthering this line of thought even more, how much can a questioner (or answerer) take for granted?  For whatever theological position one holds, in theory, according to Dottard's logic, one would have to put forth an exegetical thesis and thoroughly justify *many* theological conclusions just to earn the right to ask a question.

Comment: @NigelJ Thanks. I updated the link. It should work now.

Comment: I think that this question is fully answered in the Tour and the Help sections offered by the site (see below).

Comment: I once tried answering this question: https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/867/423 which you may find helpful

Comment: Glad to see that the Q in the link has had a fresh answer on Jan. 12th so it seems to have been unlocked. My only comment is that if I do not think a Q to be "a proper question", I move on to one that is. Different people have different ideas as to what constitutes "a proper Q". The Moderators must remove ones that don't fit the Stack criteria, leaving us to decide on the rest for ourselves!